# Can I use a capital ẞ in Palatino / tufte class

Tags: tufte, classicthesis

I'm using the tufte-handout class, which sets the text in Palatino, I believe. Is there a way to make `\textsc{ß}` render as "ẞ"? (currently it  renders as "SS".)

Answer (score 0):

This gives me ẞ when writing \textsc{ß}

```
\documentclass[a4paper,de-DE]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\babeltags{de = ngerman}
\babeltags{en = english}
% the next line makes text figures proportional, oldstyle, while math uses lining figures
\usepackage[theoremfont,trueslanted,largesc,tighter,p,osf]{newpxtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc / must be loaded before amsthm, if using amsthm
\usepackage{units} % Non-stacked fractions and better unit spacing
\usepackage{amsthm} % must be loaded before newpxmath
\usepackage[vvarbb]{newpxmath}
```

(adapted from https://ctan.kako-dev.de/fonts/newpx/doc/newpxdoc.pdf )